# How to copy the output of command `pwd`, which is echoed in the echo area?

Tags: copy-paste, echo-area, kill-ring

After executing the command `pwd`, Emacs minibuffer successfully returns the file location, for instance: `Directory /home/pedro/projects/`.

I can see that information. But I would also like to copy it.

How can I copy this information (add it to the kill ring)?

Comment: `C-u M-! "shell-command" RET` inserts the output of the command in the current buffer. To copy it to the clipboard ring you'd have to write a custom function.

Comment: Additionally, the output of most (if not all) commands goes to the `*Messages*` buffer. If you happen to run a command and you want its output for whatever reason, you can just go to that buffer and copy it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `C-h f` to read the documentation:

```
Signature
(pwd &optional INSERT)

Documentation
Show the current default directory.

With prefix argument INSERT, insert the current default directory
at point instead.
```

The bit about the prefix argument means that if you run it with `C-u` it will insert the path into the current buffer instead.

Comment: And to get that copied to the kill-ring use...